# asp.net mvc viewdata to display category name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using ado.net entity model from an existing database.
I am using two  tables products and categories.

I have a product controller:

```
public ActionResult Products()
        {

            using (var db = new StoreMvcEntities())
            {
                ViewData["categories"] = db.Categories.ToList();

                return View(db.Products.ToList());
            }
        }
```

and a view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
            </td>
            <td>

               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.category.categoryname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Here is the problem: in the controller, if I remove the `ViewData["categories"] = db.Categories.ToList();` the product category name is empty in the view. I'm not using the `ViewData["categories"]` in the view, and to get to product category name, I have to invoke
`db.Categories` and affect the result to any viewdata.

Can anybody explain to me how this is working?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're running into a side effect of Model Binding.  Does the `Products` class have a property for the `Category` class?

Comment: the product class has only categoryid